# Is the amount of followers limited?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just got my first follower, and I'm wondering if I can get a second person to follow me. Is the game limited to one or two follower(s) or does it allow for a large number of followers? It really seems handy to me to have some followers protect me when I draw attention from a larger group, or when I try to steal something where I really shouldn't...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Skyrim, how many followers can I have? And where do I get them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36714/in-skyrim-how-many-followers-can-i-have-and-where-do-i-get-them)

Comment: No, that's a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PC players can use the console to allow more than one follower at a time. After obtaining a follower, the PlayerFollowerCount global varable is set to 1. Setting it back to 0 will enable you to obtain another follower.

To set PlayerFollowerCount to zero, open the console (default <kbd>~</kbd>), type in `set PlayerFollowerCount to 0`, hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, then close the console <kbd>~</kbd>.

Comment: This is not working for me, when using this cheat i still get one and only one follower, the previous one leave me behind

Answer (score 8):

The game limits the amount of followers to:

- One recruitable follower
- Unlimited [quest followers](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Skyrim:Multiple_Followers). People who will follow Dovahkiin untill a specific task is completed.

If you want to expand the original recruitable follower limit the mod below solves the problem:

### Extensible Follower Framework

**[Extensible Follower Framework](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=12933)** is a mod that allows up to **100 Dovahkiin followers**. In the following picture 16 of them are chilling at Breezehome, Whiterun.

[image]

### Main features

- Recruit up to 100 followers at once
- Follower commands are executed via menu rather than dialogue
- Followers stats (combat, skills, magic, etc) can be displayed
- Followers mount horses
- Followers can "collect" or "harvest" items
- Followers can "relax"
- Followers outfit can be edited
- Followers stats can be "updated" via the "Train" command
- Followers can dual wield
- Followers can be assigned to be "Default", "Protected", or "Essential"
- Any available command can also be applied to the **entire group** at once

### Isn't the game too easy then?

Not exactly. Keep in mind attacking and bleeding are key factors to level up. That means you're still very vulnerable to strong attacks but still won't waste your time dueling boring enemies. This mod has a greater level of awesome against multiple enemies featured by [**war mods**](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=9494).

Answer (score 7):

I had a pretty big party rolling down the land of skyrim. Riding the immortal horse **Shaddowmere**, find **Barbos** the immortal dog (just don't complete the quest and he follows you to the end of the game).

At one point in the main story you get the option to travel with **Delphine** and the other blade **Esbern**, who summons 2 Atronaches. I found **a hunter** whose friends were torn apart by bears, give him a potion and tell him you'll avenge his friends (don't finish the sidequest) and he follows you till the end of the game. Master conjuring to get **two Atronaches** plus your follower using a staff of the familiar and bam: **11 man party**:

- Hero (you)
- 2 summons
- Follower

  - His summon
- Horse
- Dog
- Hunter
- 2 blades with one summon.

Answer (score 6):

You can only have 1 follower at a time, without glitching. If you try to recruit more, they will say you already have someone.

I know in previous Bethesda games you could glitch out and get 7-8, but I do not think it possible in this one.

Answer (score 3):

"**Permanent followers** usually become available after you complete a [quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests) of some kind. You can also find mercenaries for hire in the cities and recruit certain [creatures](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Creatures) in the game. You can have at most one permanent NPC follower and one creature follower at any time.

Some NPCs follow you **temporarily** for the duration of a quest. If you avoid completing the quest and go somewhere else, they may follow you around. As many of these NPCs are unkillable, and you can have several followers at the same time, you can use them to fight difficult enemies in a different questline.

Potential followers will say that you already have a follower and be unable to join you if you are on a quest that gives you a temporary follower. In such cases the quest follower already occupies the follower slot until the quest is completed. For example, in the Proving Honor quest, Farkas will occupy the follower slot even if you have not yet gone to meet him at Dustman's Cairn. The slot can be freed again simply by completing the quest so that your temporary quest follower leaves your service."

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "**Followers**" article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers)</sup>
You can allow more followers using the mod, [**UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul**](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/14037). One of its features is:

> Amount of followers you can have accompany you has been raised to 15 (not including dogs or quest NPCs).

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have 2 followers (that I can trade with) without any cheat or mods, not sure if it's a bug though.

I had Serena from the Dawnguard expansion. She is a quest NPC, but at the same time I can dismiss her, so I thought she was acting as a normal follower. So I took her in my team a while ago.

Recently I finished a quest with the khajiit Kharjo and upon completion he offers me to join me if I wish. I accepted thinking Serena would leave my party, but then both stays in, so it gives me more storage space.

I'll keep it like that for a bit if they are not too much in my way all the time.