# Is there a finite amount of followers in the game world?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

To start, I'm not asking how many followers I can have at one time. I know that's been asked before a few times.

I'm wondering if there is a finite number of followers available through the world who will follow me? It seems like there is at least one in each towns inn, and then some others around based on quests. I've had a bad habit of killing them off (Unrelenting force over the cliff, so sorry Lydia) and not realizing it, but I prefer to just continue on and not reload from a save.

At some point, if I kill them all off (on acccident, of course), will I run out of people who will offer to follow me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Skyrim, how many followers can I have? And where do I get them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36714/in-skyrim-how-many-followers-can-i-have-and-where-do-i-get-them)

Comment: @Bora While Mark did appear to answer this as an extra part to that question posed (which I hadn't seen), this question is different than the other (at least in my mind). Similar answer doesn't make something a duplicate question.

Comment: Mark answers your question completely. You are asking if there is a finite number of followers available. He says, I quote, "Followers can be found all over the world: it'll be hard to avoid finding followers. There are 45 in total: ..", under which he lists them.

Comment: @Bora He does indeed. But, the question you mention as a duplicate doesn't ask how many followers there are, it asks "... can I have another companion?" The question isn't the same. I've always seen close as duplicate as being "Duplicate Question", because that's how the description reads. I suppose this is a [better discussion for meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/951/should-different-questions-that-yield-similar-duplicate-answers-be-closed), I suppose others can decide if it's a duplicate.

Comment: I understand your motivation, but it's irrelevant what is asked, if the answers are identical. Because, it is not the question what matters, it's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some generic NPCs that you gain by completing quests, such as the [Dark Brotherhood Initiate](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Brotherhood_Initiate) that may respawn, assuming you can somehow kill them in the first place.

It seems that those initiates are immortal, according to the wiki.

So no, you can't run out of followers.

Comment: ...Immortal when attacked by npcs or immortal if I kill them?

Comment: @Coomie try it and find out :)

Answer (score -3):

there is unlimited followers in skyrim because you always find someone that wants you to do something then once your done then you might see at the bottom it will say follow me I need your help then they will follow you.(don't have another follower with you)

Comment: Do you understand what "infinity" means? The number of people who want favors from you is limited, ergo not infinite.