# Two followers glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was wondering if you could have two named followers or if that is just with the DB recruit, one named follower and the slow time shout?

I was wondering if you could have two main followers in addition to the extra "quest" followers

Comment: 1 follower. The shout for the assassin is not a follower if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You can get serana and a modded follower

Comment: Related question, maybe a duplicate: [How many quest followers could one gather at once?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/48909)

Answer (score 0):

Without mods, you can only have one normal follower at a time. However, sometimes NPCs will follow you as part of a quest without taking up your normal follower slot. You can't trade with quest followers, but many of them will follow you wherever you go and fight with you. UESP has a list of quest followers [here](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Quest_Followers). In theory, you could accrue over a dozen followers this way, if you start a lot of quests but then never finish them.

Notably, when you first meet [Serana](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Serana), she will start following you without replacing your existing follower. (Actually, she follows you whether you like it or not.) She's essential and fairly strong, so she makes a good second follower, unless her attitude bugs you.

Additionally, you can have one pet travel with you. Animals use a different follower slot than people, so you can recruit a stray dog, for example, even if you already have a human follower. UESP has a [list of creatures](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Creatures) that will follow you.

I haven't heard of a glitch that lets you have more than one normal follower at a time, although it seems that people occasionally experience a [glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44880) that prevents them from having any followers at all.

Comment: I don't use mods because I don't know how to get them on ps4

Answer (score -2):

There are mods which allow you to have far more than two followers. Go to the overhaul section in skyrim nexus website and you will probably find something.